# passing javascript variable from view to controller PHP MVC

Tags: php

I am working on PHP MVC framework ,now i want to pass a variable from view to the controller ,
may i know how to do this and how to access this variable in the controller function?
thanks

Comment: Javascript lives entirely outside your MVC structure on the client! Have you heard about or looked into AJAX?

Comment: There is no solution in frameworks here. but if you struggling about passing vars from client side to server side etc. then here is a very detailed article: http://goo.gl/dR1Cv There are other related articles.

Comment: What MVC you are using?